# Safari drag drop download

Tags: safari

On previous versions of OS X I used to be able to go to a file in Safari, click and drag on the favicon and take it over to my downloads window, which would then download that file.

So for instance if i was listening to [this file](http://www.kickassclassical.com/chopin-etude-10-12-revolutionary.mp3) and wanted to download it in Lion. All I had to do was drag the icon in the address bar over to the download window.

Now I can't do that anymore. In fact I have no idea how to download that file except to make a webpage with the a href and then right click the link.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in Safari 6.x when the location bar has focus, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> brings up the export dialog to save the current page as an archive.

That's not what you want, however.

You want to download some component from a site like an mp3 or a Java jar that you know the path to, but there's no exposed link.

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↩</kbd> (option-return) to the rescue. Edit the URL in the location bar and press <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↩</kbd>. It will magically transfer over to the download view, just like you used to be able to drag it.

Comment: Media files are saved in the original format at least on 10.8. (Even though the format is shown as page source.)

Answer (score 1):

You can just press ⌘S, or press ⌥↩ when the location bar has focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can also right-click the media player and select the *Download Video* option in the contextual menu.